# Python SSLError "SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED". How to get the expired certificate name from the exception?

Tags: python, ssl

I'm running `aiosmtpd` on my server, and from time to time, I have the following error and stack:

```
SSL handshake failed
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f90f77c59e8>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=11 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED] sslv3 alert certificate expired (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Is there a way to know what is the certificate when catching the error from

```
sys.excepthook = handle_exception() # <= this function
```

(or any way to catch it from aiosmtpd but I'm not sure here)